# What does <ord> mean in a tibble?

Tags: r, tibble

does anyone know what  under month is and what function/code I can use to obtain my months in ? I'm trying to extract the months from a datetime column formatted in POXISct (in a tibble).

```
#>    month gender  ntrips
#>    <ord> <fct>    <int>
#>  1 Jan   unknown    428
#>  2 Jan   male      9798
#>  3 Jan   female    2451
#>  4 Feb   unknown    498
#>  5 Feb   male     11849
#>  6 Feb   female    2757
#>  7 Mar   unknown    794
#>  8 Mar   male     13231
#>  9 Mar   female    3084
#> 10 Apr   unknown   1676
#> # … with 23 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

It’s short for “[ordered factor](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/factor.html)”. In other words, a variable for which `is.ordered(x)` is `TRUE`.

To extract the months, use `df$month` (assuming your table is called `df`). However, you can’t directly convert the values into `POSIXct` format, since a month isn’t a date: it’s missing the year and day component.